# How do I override Jenkins's URL child prefix in a multi-branch pipeline?

Tags: jwt, jenkins-plugins, multibranch-pipeline

How do I override Jenkins's URL child prefix in a multi-branch pipeline?

We are using the context aware credential store of Conjur Secrets plugin.
We want to sync credentials to only one branch of a multi-branch pipeline.
We have configured the plugin and able to sync our credentials for the entire pipeline i.e. all branches. When we try to restrict for a single branch, we get:
`jenkins_url_child_prefix` is missing from JWT token for the pipelines `XXX` and `XXXX`. Our JWT token from a single branch looks like:

```
JWT Token:
{
    "sub": "my_name",
    "jenkins_parent_url_child_prefix": "job",
    "jenkins_parent_full_name": "multibranch_pipeline_name",
    "jenkins_parent_task_noun": "Scan",
    "jenkins_full_name": "multibranch_pipeline_name/XXXX",
    "iss": "http://example.com",
    "aud": "jenkins-projects",
    "jenkins_name": "XXXX",
    "nbf": 0000000,
    "jenkins_parent_name": "multibranch_pipeline_name",
    "identity": "jenkins-projects-XXXX",
    "name": "my_name",
    "jenkins_task_noun": "Build",
    "exp": 000000,
    "iat": 000000,
    "jenkins_pronoun": "Branch",
    "jti": "BADF00D",
    "jenkins_job_buildir": "/var/jenkins_home/jobs/multibranch_pipeline_name/branches/XXXX/builds"
}
```

I believe `job` is the default child prefix but it wants `jenkins_url_child_prefix` specifically. Is there any way to override it in our multi-branch configuration?